# Numpy Covariance Matrix numpy.cov

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, sympy, covariance

I am using numpy and want to compute the covariance matrix for an ndarray. I am trying to use numpy.cov() but am not getting the correct results. More details below.

My ndarray is 768x8 for where 8 is the numbers features in my data set.

When I use MATLAB to compute the covariance matrix, I get a 8x8 (which is what I require), but when I use np.cov(), I get a 768x768 which is incorrect. I tried changing the rowvar argument to true and this does not work.

What would be the correct call to numpy.cov()? In other words, how would I reproduce the cov() results from MATLAB using numpy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Amazingly, the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) might tell you.  You should pass `rowvar=False` to indicate that columns represent variables.

```
>>> data.shape
(768, 8)
>>> numpy.cov(data, rowvar=False).shape
(8, 8)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I did refer to the documentation but didn't realize that the default for rowvar is True (and not False)!

Comment: If transpose if passed to numpy.cov it should yield 8 X 8 Matrix.

Answer (score 1):

as per default, each row is observation, each column is feature, which is swaped in numpi  per definition, so all you need to do is transpose, where R is matrix

```
np.cov(R.T)
```

or

```
np.cov(R, rowvar = False)
```